# Sometimes opening in read only mode

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-powerpoint, read-only

I have a client that is running Windows 7 Pro on a domain, and PowerPoint 2010 sometimes when opens in read only mode.

- Server 2008 R2
- Full rights to shared file and folder
- doesn't happen all the time
- File not open by another user

Did preform:

- Open Windows explorer, Organize, Layout Details Planeck and unchecked
- Ran CCleaner and clean all cache and temp files

Comment: Note that MS office files on a network share often open in readonly mode if another user already has it open, or if they previously had the file open, and then closed it client side without notifying the file (perhaps by killing the task or shutting down and force closing applications). if you have admin access to the server, you can check to see if any processes have file handles on the document before you attempt to open it, if you want to test.

Comment: Frank is correct that network files can be left open when they really shouldn't be (I can think of a couple other ways this can happen, too).  But I suspect in each of those cases PPT would give you the "Another user ...blah blah...do you want to open a copy" message.  Are you getting that?   If not, right click the file in Win Explorer, choose Properties and look to see if there's an UNBLOCK button on the properties page.  If so, click it and try opening the file again.